# Terminating a blocked pthreads thread

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, file-descriptor

I Have a thread that reads data from a file descriptor, using `select()` to block until the data is available.
When the program needs to terminate, I need to close the thread, however it's blocked on select.

My question, is it a good practice to notify the thread about my intentions to terminate by closing the file-descriptor ?

is there a better method to notify the thread ?
I know there's always an option to use signal, however I've read in some places that signals the `pthreads` doesn't work together that well.

Comment: why you set `select` to be blocked all the time?Give it a timeout!When reaching the timeout and no events occurred, loop check a flag that determine whether it has to run continuously.

Comment: What happens if you close the FD from another thread?

Comment: Select will return with error code in the thread.

Comment: OK, sounds good to me.  Cetainly sounds better than some shabby timeout loop that introduces avoidable CPU waste and termination latency.  It seems that it works, and it's one-line. How much 'better' could there be?

Comment: I feel that it's a good method, however, Someone said to me that's abusing the interface. I just want to know if there's a better way to do it, so far, I win... :)

Comment: 'abusing the interface' guy/gal is the developer whose multithreaded apps respond poorly and will not shut down immediately, (ie clueless).  Every time you click on any 'Close' icon and the app just locks up for seconds before actually terminating is written by 'abusing the interface' developers.

Comment: ..and would probably be the same developers who insist on 'manually' deleting/destroying every struct and object in every thread before exiting the app, no matter how much extra coding, debugging, testing is required to try and achieve what the OS can already do without raising a sweat.

Comment: The FUD level re. multithreading is so high that it's almost impossible to see over it.  Your experience is very common - you develop something that works well, every time, and then someone tells you you've done it wrong and you must rewrite it to be inefficient, slow and buggy.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can use a pipe, and add that to your read-set. Send a single byte on the pipe when the thread should terminate.

Or have a timeout on the `select` call, and when it timeouts check for termination flag.

Comment: by adding timeout I add overhead to the thread, to be fast enough I need to wake-up about every second...

Comment: @Mellowcandle You could have a timeout of one millisecond, and it still wouldn't be noticeable on the CPU load.

Comment: ..or, it seems, just close the fd.  One-liner, no CPU-wasting timeout loop or avoidable latency.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the gentle ways proposed by *Joachim*, there also are some rough appoaches to 
"interrupt" the blocking `select()`:

- use `pthread_kill()` to send a signal to the blocking thread and test for `(EINTR == errno)` after the `select()` in question
- call `pthread_cancel()` on the thread-id. `select()` belongs to the set of default cancellation points.

Both methods should be considert as last ressort solutions.